# Is it possible to style a file input type so that it would still allow drag and drop?

Tags: html, css

Found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4cwpLvae/) shown below which styles the input button so when clicked it will open the file explorer. Can you have a similar button which would support the ability to drag and drop like the regular input does?

```
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your example you're setting the `display` attribute of the actual input to `none`, removing the regular behavior of being able to drag and drop.

I think the best you can do with this example, using just CSS and HTML is to set the opacity to 0 and overlay the file input on top of your custom button, but it's a bit tacky, I'd suggest maybe some clever jQuery usage if you want to get expansive with it and actually show what file is being uploaded and such.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4cwpLvae/1042/

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
    <br>
    <input placeholder="none" id="file-upload" type="file"/>
</label>
```